# Add multiple docked widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I try to add multiple tabified QDockWidgets but somehow I can only have to docked at the same time.

mwe code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class DockWindow(QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        super().__init__(parent)

        parent.addDockWidget(Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, self)
        self.setWindowTitle(name)
        child = parent.findChildren(DockWindow)

        if len(child) > 1:
            parent.tabifyDockWidget(self, child[0])
            self.raise_()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = QMainWindow()

for i in range(10):
    DockWindow(main, str(i))


main.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#tabifyDockWidget):

> **void QMainWindow::tabifyDockWidget(QDockWidget * first, QDockWidget *
>   second)**
>
> Moves second dock widget on top of first dock widget, creating a
>   tabbed docked area in the main window.

From what is concluded in the first parameter must be the initial `QDockWidget`, if any `child[0]`, second the new `QDockWidget`, in your case `self`. The problem is solved by changing:

```
parent.tabifyDockWidget(self, child[0])
```

to:

```
parent.tabifyDockWidget(child[0], self)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for that clarification